# Trigger Build in Jenkins By EMAIL

Tags: email, hudson, jenkins, sendmail

I am Currently using Jenkins in Windows 7 .
I have recently ran some build in jenkins . I am Able to run the build by SVN Post commit .
Now i have to triiger the build in Jenkins by email.

I am a windows user and as per my knowledge Sendmail and qmail agents have to be used to trigger build in jenkins by email.But these are for Unix .

Or is there any way i can install sendmail on my windows machine and then perform the trigger.

I am A windows user and so if any plugin is there to trigger builds in jenkins .Please let me know.

thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a simple free mail client (say, [Mozilla Thunderbird](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/)) that would filter trigger e-mails in the appropriate folder. Monitor the file system location of that folder with [FSTrigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/FSTrigger+Plugin).

You do not need to read the e-mails in the folder. What you do is this: for each build create an e-mail folder, create a filter that sorts e-mails by subject (subjects would be something like "Trigger [job-name]" ). And monitor modifications to those folders via the plugin. My Thunderbird folders, for example, are stored locally in `C:/Users/[user_name]/AppData/Roaming/Thunderbird/Profiles/9nby4v95.default/Mail/Local Folders/` But you can configure Thunderbird to put them wherever you want.

Comment: i did it by monitoring the file "C:\Users\[Username]\AppData\Roaming\Thunderbird\Profiles\yedw4kwp.default\Mail\mail server\Foldername"    . And this Foldername is a file which have filtered mails by subject. So when a new mail arrives this file is modified and then the plugin detects it and the build is triggerd. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I wrote the following Jenkins plugin about 3 months ago, to do just this:

<strike>https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/poll-mailbox-trigger-plugin</strike>
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Poll+Mailbox+Trigger+Plugin.

Check it out, read the documentation, let me know if this solves your problem.

All documentation is on gitHub now:

https://github.com/jenkinsci/poll-mailbox-trigger-plugin

Comment: I tried to use this plugin but I can't seem to get it to work with an SMTP MS exchange server.
I asked a question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44148581/jenkins-poll-mailbox-trigger-plugin-and-smtp
If you could take a look and try help me out I would really appreciate it!